# Question about error: Error in etsmodel(y, errortype[i], trendtype[j], seasontype[k], damped[l], : unused argument (method = "naive")

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, forecast

I have a Price vector like this:
Price=rnorm(n=44, mean=510, sd=10)

Every number is one-month's observation for the price of a certain product, I would like to forecast the next 6 month or 4 month's price.

But got this error

Error in etsmodel(y, errortype[i], trendtype[j], seasontype[k], damped[l],  : 
  unused argument (method = "naive")

Every number is one-month's observation for the price of a certain product, I would like to forecast the next 6 month or 4 month's price. I firstly decompose the curve into seasonal, trend and random component, because there is not much autoregressive correlation between the current values and the previous value.

```
monthlyts=ts(Price, start = c(2016,1), frequency = 12)
mode(monthlyts)
#--------------------------------------------------------
#decompose the time series into trend and seasonal components
decom = decompose(monthlyts,type ='multi')
plot(decom)
#-----------------------------
fcast<-forecast(decom$x,method="naive",h=6)
plot(fcast)
```

I see this error.

Error in etsmodel(y, errortype[i], trendtype[j], seasontype[k], damped[l],  : 
  unused argument (method = "naive")

Could anyone pls advise how to fix this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`decom$x` contains the original time series data `monthlyts` which is of class `ts`.

So `forecast()` will call `forecast.ts()` which calls `ets()` to fit a model. `ets()` does not have a `method` argument, so it returns an error.

If you just want forecasts of the original data, then the following will work.

```r
fit <- ets(monthlyts)
fcast <- forecast(fit, h=6)
plot(fcast)
```

Comment: Actually my purpose is to forecast decom$seasonal, in that case, I have to use the ts.Otherwise I can't use decompose() function. I have tried this method with my other data, which is a daily time series. It worked. Not sure what's the problem now. But thanks for the advice!

Comment: The seasonal component is periodic. You don't need a model to forecast it.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is just an example, I would like to forecast the trend component and the random component, so can can forecast the future values of the time series. Because this time series seems have very less autocorrelation from the values in the previous timestamp.